# Computability function - how to express it in set theory/arithmetic hierarchy

Tags: logic, set-theory, computability

Let's say that $f$ is computable function such
that for particular inputs $x$ and $y$, $f(x) = 0$
and $f(y) = 0$.

If we want to express this in logical form
(arithmetic hierarchy formula), what would it be
like? Or is this impossible to be represented in
first-order logic?

$x$ and $y$ are specific (fixed) numbers.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ specific, known numbers (like $15$ or $10^{10^{100}}$?), or are they unknown but you want to state that such numbers exist?

Comment: Specific numbers (so sets)

Comment: The arithmetical hierarchy contains sets. It does not talk explicitly talk about functions.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon I think it talks about functions too: $f \in \Sigma^{0}_{n}$ iff its graph is $\Sigma^{0}_{n}$.

Comment: @QuinnCulver : Thanks for pointing that out. I was not familiar with that convention.

Answer (score 1):

For a given function $f$, the statement that the computation of $f(x)$ halts and returns a number $z$ is a $\Sigma^0_1$ formula. The conjunction of two $\Sigma^0_1$ formulas is again $\Sigma^0_1$.